# TFS Web Access Excruciatingly Slow

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, tfs

I'm in need of some guidance. My company is running TFS 2010 and any time a user attempts to access Team Web Access it is blindingly slow. We also have Urban Turtle installed and when we try to bring up the planning board tab that takes forever, too (~15 - 20 seconds).

Here's the setup:

Application Tier (Virtual Machine)

- Windows Server 2008R2
- IIS 7
- TFS 2010 SP1 & latest patches
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Analysis and
  Reporting Services
- 2x 2.5GHz CPUs
- 8GB RAM
- 2x 80GB HDDs (C: & E:)

Data Tier (Virtual Machine)

- Windows Server 2012R2
- SQL Server 2008R2 SP2 CU4
- 4x 2.5GHz CPUs
- 16GB RAM
- 4x HDDs (C: 80GB, E: 40GB Temp, F: 40GB Log, G: 300GB Data)

The data tier was virtualized back in early February. It seems like performance has degraded over time as opposed to all at once. I would think if the issue was related to virtualization, we would have seen that right away or at least much sooner.

I have moved the TFS cache to a separate drive on the App Tier. That hasn't really improved anything.

I did some defrag analysis, and the C: drive on the app tier is at 24% fragmentation and E: is at 65% fragmentation. That's terrible! My next step is to defrag these two drives during a maintenance window.

Can you guys think of anything of any other suggestions to help improve performance?

Comment: Is it slow when doing day to day operations such as Get Latest, check-ins, etc? When were they last restarted?

Comment: Seems to be ok in that regard.

Comment: When were the servers last restarted? Any other network issues? Do you restart the client machines? Are there other VMs on the same physical sever that are having any issues?

Comment: Guthwulf, thanks for taking the time to offer some ideas. I'll check on all of that and respond here.

Comment: So I just received a report from a couple of users that TFS began to slow down about an hour ago. The activities taking place were querying builds and check-ins. This slowness lasted about 15 minutes or so.

Comment: Have you heavily customised the templates? That can make thighs slow and urban turtle is a big culprit there..

Comment: To be blindingly honest there is no real excuse to still be on 2010. You should move to 2012 if you need to support ie8 and 2013 if not. You cn still use the same 2010 build build servers if you are building for xp...

Comment: MrHinsh, our build and work item templates have been customized, yes. I appreciate you're honesty and you're right. We are planning an upgrade to 2013, which should be completed by July.